# Problem with url link-`~` is replaced by %257E

Tags: hyperref, pdf, urls, acrobat, tilde

I am adding a url in my document using `\url{}`. The link, however doesn't lead to where it is suppossed to lead. My code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
        \url{http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/Class/phy319/phy319/node75.html}
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

If I click on it it takes me to

http://www.phy.duke.edu/%257Ergb/Class/phy319/phy319/node75.html

Notice that `~` is replaced by `%257E`.

Any ideas on why is this happening or how could it be fixed?

Comment: Which PDF viewer are you using?

Comment: Interesting, where is that `25` coming from. The proper url encode for tilde is `%7e`.

Comment: @giordano: Nice question... I'm using `Acrobat XI`, but I've seen that in `Nitro` and `Sumatra` is working as it is suppossed to work...

Comment: @daleif: I don't have the foggiest idea!

Comment: @Thanos it works also in Evince and Okular. Bug in Adobe Reader?

Comment: It seems so: http://forums.adobe.com/message/5162453

Comment: @Thanos, what happens if you use `\url{http://www.phy.duke.edu/%7ergb/Class/phy319/phy319/node75.html}`, will Acrobat Accept it then? To a browser `~` and `%7e` is the same thing.

Comment: @daleif: I tried that first thing, but it seems that `%` is recognised as a comment symbol event indide the `\url{}`...

Comment: @Thanos, does it compile or not? I have no problem compiling with `\url{...%7e...}` on my TL13 system. You editor might not know about syntax highlighting `\url`

Comment: @daleif: It doesn't compile. I am using `TeXNiC center`. The `\url{}` is inside `\footnote{}` so it tells me that `footnote` is incomplete.

Comment: Then please update your mwe. It is not easy to help when we do not have all info. In many cases you may get away with \protect\url

Answer (score 6):

I have seen/analyzed the problem some time ago. The reason is a buggy PDF viewer (some versions of AR), see giordano's comments.

Package `hyperref` writes the URL into the PDF fil, e.g. pdfTeX or dvips/ps2pdf:

```
/URI(http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/Class/phy319/phy319/node75.html)
```

The more canonical URI would be with percent encoding:

```
http://www.phy.duke.edu/%7Ergb/Class/phy319/phy319/node75.html
```

But the bug duplicates this step.

**Clumsy workaround:** URL shortening services (TinyURL and other) without special characters in the generated URL to replace the URL in the PDF file. Also possible with `\href`:

```
\href{<short URL with harmless characters>}{\nolinkurl{<original URL>}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I could use `\href{http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/Class/phy319/phy319/node75.html}{\nolinkurl{here}}` but in this way I am dealing with the same problem. If I use the character `%` it will comment everything after it...
If I use `\href{http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/Class/phy319/phy319/node75.html}{\nolinkurl{http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/Class/phy319/phy319/node75.html}}` it won't take me to the website(that's the `\nolinkurl{}` I suspect)...

Comment: @Thanos: In `\href` you could escape `%` by `\%`, but it does not help here, because `~` is a special character in URLs that get percent encoded anyway, triggering the bug in the PDF viewer.

Comment: Exactly! I believe I have just to work with the reader... to "fix" somehow the bug...